# How to set Accordion opened all as default in Ant-design-mobile?

Tags: reactjs

I am using Ant-design-mobile library in reactjs.
How to set Accordion that are opened all as default ?

```
<Accordion defaultActiveKey="all" className="my-accordion" onChange={this.onChange}>
          <Accordion.Panel header="Title 1">text </Accordion.Panel>
          <Accordion.Panel header="Title 2" className="pad">text </Accordion.Panel>
          <Accordion.Panel header="Title 3" className="pad">text </Accordion.Panel>
        </Accordion>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on these docs:

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-mobile/blob/master/components/accordion/index.tsx
https://github.com/fis-components/rc-collapse/blob/master/README.md

I think you just need to pass `accordion` props.

```
<Accordion accordion={true} defaultActiveKey="all" className="my-accordion" onChange={this.onChange}>
      <Accordion.Panel header="Title 1">text </Accordion.Panel>
      <Accordion.Panel header="Title 2" className="pad">text </Accordion.Panel>
      <Accordion.Panel header="Title 3" className="pad">text </Accordion.Panel>
</Accordion>
```